# Argument of type 'Ref<x>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'x'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Using the new Composition API I am trying to get data from an input and pass it to a function which expects a `string`. However, TypeScript is complaining the types don't match up because one is a `Ref<>`. What am I supposed to do here?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import formHandler from '../utils/formHandler'

const name = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <div class="form">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input name="name" v-model="name"/>
    <button @click="formHandler.validate(name)">Validate</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please share the code of `formHandler`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it out. You have to append `.value` to get the value itself.

```
const name = ref('')

name       // <-- Ref object
name.value // <-- string
```